# Conditional code in the define_method block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am generating some methods on the fly. The method body varies based on a certain criteria. 
I was relying on class_eval to generate conditional code.

```
%Q{
  def #{name}
   #{
   (name != "password") ? "attributes[:#{name}]" : 
                         "encrypt(attributes[:#{name}])"
   }
  end
}
```

Recently I have started using define_method. How do I generate conditional code blocks while using define_method?

**Edit 1**

Here are the possible approaches that I have considered:

1) Checking the name on during run time:

```
define_method(name) do       
 if name == password
   decrypt(attributes[name])     
 else
   attributes[name]
 end
end
```

This is not a preferred method as the check is done during run time.

2) Conditionally defining the entire method.

```
if (name == "password")
 define_method(name) do       
   decrypt(attributes[name])     
 end
else
 define_method(name) do       
   attributes[name]
 end
end
```

This approach has the disadvantage of having to repeat the code block just change a small part (as my actual method has several lines of code).

Answer (score 3):

I think because of closures you can do something like this:

```
  define_method name do
    if name=='password'
      decrypt(attributes[name])
    else
      attributes[name]
    end
  end
```

But the issue there is that the if will be evaluated on each call to the method.
If you wanted to avoid that you'd need to pass different blocks to `define_method` for different behavior. e.g.

```
if name=='password'
  define_method(name) { decrypt(attributes[name]) }
else
  define_method(name) { attributes[name] }
end
```

alternately you could pass a `lambda` chosen by the if statement.

```
define_method(name, name=='password' ? lambda { decrypt(attributes[name]) } : lambda { attributes[name] }
```

One thing to think about, define_method can be slower than using eval.

Comment: +1, I have considered both approaches you have proposed. I have rejected the first approach for obvious reasons. Second approach is what I am doing now, but I have to repeat my code twice. Actual method I am adding has a bigger method body. so it is an eye-sore.

Comment: I am curious about the last sentence, do you have any links that talks about this issue?

Comment: After doing some searching about, it looks like it is a fair bit slower than using `def`, but eval isn't all that different. I didn't find any recent benchmarks though and something like this is very interpreter dependent.